# want to sync a javascript countdown to server time, not to client time

Tags: javascript, countdown, countdowntimer

I want my time to count down to one time for every client (server time) and not to the time they have on their computer. This is my countdown, how do i do this ?

This is the timer that should count down to one date for everybody so everybody around the would see the timer drops to 0 at the same time.

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var ringer = {
          countdown_to: "07/20/2017 6:00 PM",
          rings: {
            'DAYS': { 
              s: 86400000, // mseconds in a day,
              max: 365
            },
            'HOURS': {
              s: 3600000, // mseconds per hour,
              max: 24
            },
            'MINUTES': {
              s: 60000, // mseconds per minute
              max: 60
            },
            'SECONDS': {
              s: 1000,
              max: 60
            }
           },
          r_count: 4,
          r_spacing: 10, // px
          r_size: 200, // px
          r_thickness: 30, // px
          update_interval: 11, // ms


          init: function(){

            $r = ringer;
            $r.cvs = document.createElement('canvas'); 

            $r.size = { 
              w: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) * $r.r_count + ($r.r_spacing*($r.r_count-1)), 
              h: ($r.r_size + $r.r_thickness) 
            };



            $r.cvs.setAttribute('width',$r.size.w);           
            $r.cvs.setAttribute('height',$r.size.h);
            $r.ctx = $r.cvs.getContext('2d');
            $(".countdownwrap").append($r.cvs);
            $r.cvs = $($r.cvs);    
            $r.ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            $r.actual_size = $r.r_size + $r.r_thickness;
            $r.countdown_to_time = new Date($r.countdown_to).getTime();
            $r.cvs.css({ maxWidth: $r.size.w+"px", maxHeight: $r.size.h+"px",width: "90%", height: "19%"});
            $r.go();
          },
          ctx: null,
          go: function(){
            var idx=0;

            $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) - $r.countdown_to_time;


            for(var r_key in $r.rings) $r.unit(idx++,r_key,$r.rings[r_key]);      

            setTimeout($r.go,$r.update_interval);
          },
          unit: function(idx,label,ring) {
            var x,y, value, ring_secs = ring.s;
            value = parseFloat($r.time/ring_secs);
            $r.time-=Math.round(parseInt(value)) * ring_secs;
            value = Math.abs(value);

            x = ($r.r_size*.5 + $r.r_thickness*.5);
            x +=+(idx*($r.r_size+$r.r_spacing+$r.r_thickness));
            y = $r.r_size*.5;
            y += $r.r_thickness*.5;


            // calculate arc end angle
            var degrees = 360-(value / ring.max) * 360.0;
            var endAngle = degrees * (Math.PI / 180);

            $r.ctx.save();

            $r.ctx.translate(x,y);
            $r.ctx.clearRect($r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size*-0.5,$r.actual_size,$r.actual_size);

            // first circle
            $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(10,22,51, 1)";
            $r.ctx.beginPath();
            $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,2 * Math.PI, 2);
            $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
            $r.ctx.stroke();

            // second circle
            $r.ctx.strokeStyle = "rgba(23,149,210,1)";
            $r.ctx.beginPath();
            $r.ctx.arc(0,0,$r.r_size/2,0,endAngle, 1);
            $r.ctx.lineWidth =$r.r_thickness;
            $r.ctx.stroke();

            // label
            $r.ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";

            $r.ctx.font = '16px Helvetica';
            $r.ctx.fillText(label, 0, 40);


            $r.ctx.font = 'bold 80px Helvetica';
            $r.ctx.fillText(Math.floor(value), 0, 18);

            $r.ctx.restore();
          }
        }

        ringer.init();
    </script>
```

Comment: What does all the canvas stuff have to do with your question? Can you shorten your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var xmlHttp;
    function srvTime(){
    try {
        //FF, Opera, Safari, Chrome
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (err1) {
        //IE
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Msxml2.XMLHTTP');
        }
        catch (err2) {
            try {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.
            catch (eerr3) {
                //AJAX not supported, use CPU time.
                alert("AJAX not supported");
            }
        }
    }
                 xmlHttp.open('HEAD',window.location.href.toString(),false);
xmlHttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
xmlHttp.send('');
return xmlHttp.getResponseHeader("Date");
}

var st = srvTime();
var date = new Date(st);
```

I found this solution for what you want to do by using Ajax

Comment: Call the function when you want to use server time

Comment: $r.time = (new Date().getTime()) -       $r.countdown_to_time;

Comment: $r.time=(srvTime())-$r.countdown_to_time;

Answer (score 1):

What server operating system and web server software are you using?

Instead of initializing the time in JavaScript, you could send the client the page with an initialized time that gets resolved in the moment the user requested the page with [PHP](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_date.asp), but if you want the server to count down for you you would need to write an [XML HttpRequest](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_http.asp) to continue requesting the current time on an interval.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to convert to whatever timezone the server is using (should be using UTC/GMT).

```
function convertUTCToLocal(dateFromServer) {
    var now = new Date();
    return dateFromServer.setMinutes(dateFromServer.getMinutes - now.getTimezoneOffset());
}
```